# What's the difference between vacuum pump and vacuum cleaner?

Tags: vacuum

I think vacuum pump and vacumm cleaner's structure is almost same.Isn't it?

Comment: In general, yes.

Comment: Nope, not even close... a vacuum cleaner is optimized for flow at a very modest pressure differential while a vacuum pump causes a very high pressure differential at a modest flow (unless you have a lot of money and a lot of electrical power...).

Comment: Not to mention that "vacuum pump" is  a generic term that can include ion pumps, getters, etc.

Comment: In one system of nomenclature, machines that move air may be categorized as "fans" (moves a high volume against a small pressure difference), "compressors" (moves a small volume against a large pressure difference), or "blowers" (somewhere in the middle).  In that system, A vacuum cleaner belongs to the "blower" category, and a vacuum system _fore pump_ belongs in the compressor category.  Other things called "vacuum pump" (see @CarlWitthoft 's comment) don't fit any of the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vacuum cleaner motor is a fan that spins very fast and has vanes on it. The vanes spin the air and the air is thrown to the outside by centrifugal force. This creates a large flow of air but the pressure is limited. Since the centrifugal action requires air to be flowing through the fan, this type of pump will stall if the airflow drop below a certain critical amount. That's why if you put your hand over the end of the hose of your vacuum, it revs really high and doesn't such your hand into the hose. The fan stalls and pressures are typically limited to 1-5psi less than atmospheric pressure. Vacuum pumps on the other hand, use different designs but a piston design is pretty common. It uses a piston that moves up and down and valves that only allow air to flow in one direction. The total airflow is much less with this type of pump, but because of the valves, it won't stall at low airflow rates. As a result, vacuum pumps can reach extremely low pressures.

Comment: Turbomolecular vacuum pumps are just a fan that spin very fast and work in pretty much the same way. They reach much lower pressures than displacement pumps

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you need different technologies to reach different levels of vaccum. All have limits about how far they can pump out, but also several can be efficient only at low enough initial density.  A vaccum cleaner cannot decrease a lot the pressure.  Several techniques are presented on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_pump).